# How can i change directory in the terminal in VS Code?

Tags: reactjs, terminal, directory

I want my terminal to look like the one on the left so that i can create a new directory but the terminal in my Vs code looks like the one on the right. What can i do to change it like the one on the left? Please help me! Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: The reason the terminals look different is because the video is using either a macOS or Linux system which has the `zsh` terminal as default. Where you are on Windows so the default terminal is `Powershell` . You still should be able to follow the tutorial regardless of the different terminals

Answer (score 1):

The picture on the left with the youtube video is using a Mac with zsh terminal installed. From the picture in the right, it looks like you use a windows machine. The current shell you are using in your VScode is powershell.

You have multiple options to get the same view as in the youtube video in your machine as listed below:

1. [How to Install zsh and Oh My Zsh in Windows 10](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-zsh-and-oh-my-zsh-windows10/#:%7E:text=Installing%20zsh%20on%20Windows%2010%201%20Open%20Bash,complete%2C%20you%E2%80%99ll%20be%20returned%20to%20the%20command%20prompt.)
2. [Make PowerShell Look like ZSH](https://dev.to/enthr/customize-powershell-to-look-like-zsh-1f24)
3. [How to install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/install-windows-subsystem-linux-windows-10)

Please feel free to try these out and experiment with the colour-themes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure the guy in the YouTube Video is using Linux as an operating system. You are using Windows so they look different.

You could use a virtual machine or install a partition next to your Windows one.

Comment: And if you want to change direcory just use the command cd